# Two numbers in a cell of a dataframe, trying to convert them in the mean

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, mean, data-manipulation

This image was extracted of a dataframe.

[image]

```
     col1                                                  col2   
0   Apple iPhone X - 64GB - Gris Espacial (Libre)          319,00        
1   IPHONE X 64GB/256GB, ENVIO DESDE ESPAÑA, GARAN.        355,00 459,00
```

What i would like to do is:
Convert the cell 355.00 459.00 in the mean of the two numbers, there are more cells with two numbers, always two, that I would like to change in the same way so I would like to make a piece of code for all the situatios where there are more than a number.

```
       col1                                               col2   
0   Apple iPhone X - 64GB - Gris Espacial (Libre)         319,00        
1   IPHONE X 64GB/256GB, ENVIO DESDE ESPAÑA, GARAN.       407
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put the sample data in text format? You can use `Ctrl`+`K` for formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, hope I did it, I´m new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the string representation into a list of floats. Check the `to_floats` methods for a solution. Split by blanks. Replace `,` with `.` to make it parseable by `float`. A cell in pandas can contain a lists. We take the mean of that list of floats using `np.mean`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'c' : ['1,0 2,0', '3,0'] })

def to_floats(s):
    '''Helper method to convert a string containing multiple
    numbers with commas into a list of floats.'''
    return [float(x.replace(',', '.')) for x in s.split()]

df['c'] = df['c'].apply(lambda x: np.mean(to_floats(x)))
```

If the column contains empty strings `''` they are converted to `NaN`. You need to decide if this makes sense for your application or not.

Comment: Change `['1.0 2.0', '3.0']` to `['1,0 2,0', '3,0']`

Answer (score 1):

In pandas, you can do the following

1. If the data in the cell is in object.str format then, convert them into list of ints for each cell
2. Now check if the length of the list in each cell. If lenght is more than 1 then take mean of it otherwise just take the only element in the list.

```py
def col2_transformation(cell_data):
    # I am assuming that cell data is in string format
    #   and numbers are separated by space
    if ' ' in cell_data:
        int_list = list(map(int, cell_data.split(' '))
        return sum(int_list) / len(int_list)
    elif cell_data:
        return int(cell_data)
    else:
        return 0 # setting a default value in case input is None


df['col2'] = df['col2'].map(col2_transformation)
```